# Android check if files exist in internal storage

Tags: android

Hi i have a string array of filenames and I'm wanting to loop through that array and check if any of the files exist in the internal files dir. If any of them don't exist i want to delete the ones that are there? does any one know how to do this?

Comment: Did you google first?

Answer (score 1):

One Way:

```
    String[] paths = ...;

    for(String path: paths){
        File file = new File(path);

        if(file.exists()) 
            file.delete();    
    }
```

And another:

```
    File dir = new File("/pathToDir");
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();

    for(File file : files){
        //You Should not Exist!!!
        file.delete();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] fileNames = {"a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"};

for(int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
    File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(fileNames[i]);

    if (file.exists()) {

        file.delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//Try this code

```
    // enter path of your dirctory
public void getDcimFolderImage(String path)
{
    File dir = new File(path);
    Log.e("path ", "is " + path);
    File file[] = dir.listFiles();

    try {
        if (file.length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) 
            {
                if (file[i].isFile()) 
                {

                    if (file.exists()
                    {
                       // enter your code whatever your want
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     // enter your code whatever your want
                    }

                }
                else 
                {
                        getDcimFolderImage(file[i].getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            File dir1 = getApplicationContext().getDir("your directory",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

              // list the folder under the directory

        for (File fdir : dir1.listFiles()) {
            if (fdir.isDirectory()) {

                //list of file under the folder

                for (File wavfile : fdir
                        .listFiles()) {
                    String str = wavfile.getName().toString();

                    if (str.equals("your delete file"))) {

                        wavfile.delete();
                    }
                }
            }
```